# Box half filled color

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, fill

I am trying kinda to make this figure in tikz but I do not know how it works.
I tried with

```
\tcbox[sharp corners, boxsep=5mm, boxrule=.5mm]
```

But I can not fill both sides with color.

[image]

Comment: Box half filled with white.

Comment: disregard the white thing. Start from the black borders.

Comment: It was a pun on pessimism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_the_glass_half_empty_or_half_full%3F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you prefer `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    sharp corners, boxsep=5mm, boxrule=.5mm,
    colback=brown, width=5cm, 
    halign upper=left, valign upper=top,
    halign lower=right, valign lower=bottom,
    enhanced, segmentation empty,
    underlay = {
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \filldraw[fill=orange, draw=tcbcolframe, line width=.5mm] (frame.south west)--++(90:1cm) to [out=5, in=185] ([yshift=-1cm]frame.north east)|-cycle;
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
}]
    A
    \tcblower
    B
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I approved this one since it is closer to my original question. I do not know though how to change position of A and B or add more text to different position inside the box.

Comment: @Geo `tcolorbox` allows to have two different paragraphs `upper` and `lower`. But these paragraphs are formatted as normal paragraphs, they won't adjust to upper or lower designs unless you use `parshape`.  About adding more text in different positions, you could always use an `overlay` but this is another question and we need more information to be able to solve it.

Comment: I meant add more text in brown or orange section. Like add "Hello" on either section but on a different position say up right or bottom left.

Comment: @Geo replace A or B for the text you want and play with  `{v|h}align {upper|lower}` options. And take a look at [`tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE. From the next time try adding a compilable MWE, so that it will attract more users to answer your question.

You can start with (borders):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw [black] (3, 2) --(3,0)--(0,0) plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) (2, 1) (3, 2)};
    \filldraw [red] (3, 2) --(0,2)--(0,0) plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) (2, 1) (3, 2)};
    \draw[yellow,  thick] (0,0)--(0,2)--(3,2)--(3,0)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

and I leave the rest of customisation for you to do `;)`.

Comment: this has no borders and if I do

`\filldraw [fill = red, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);`
Then the borders are different than tcbox
where I have
`\tcbox[sharp corners, boxsep=5mm, boxrule=.5mm]`

Comment: @Geo you can manually draw the borders around them :) see my updated answer `;)`

Comment: thanks, I also did
`\filldraw [fill = red, draw=black] [sharp corners,line width=.5mm, inner sep=5mm] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);`

What I do not understand is the coordinates, in order to change the shape
`{ (0,0) (1,1) (2, 1) (3, 2)}`
Can you point me where can I read more about it?

Comment: @Geo `Tikzpgf` manual.