# Strange behavior in TikZ \draw command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to replicate the figure in [Box half filled color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480219/box-half-filled-color) using TikZ.

I draw a rectangle from `(0,0)` to `(4,3)`.

I locate two points `(0,1)` as A and `(4,2)` as B.

When I connect the points `A` and `B`, I was expecting that the line will touch the rectangle. But there is a gap when the two points are connected.

[image]

I wish to understand this behavior.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,3);

  \node (A) at (0,1) {};
  \node (B) at (4,2) {};

  \draw (A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Vaguely related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81848/86

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is because your path joins two *nodes* (*A*) and (*B*), not the coordinates themselves. This can be made clearer by adding `draw` option to the nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,3);

  \node[draw] (A) at (0,1) {};
  \node[draw] (B) at (4,2) {};

  \draw (A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's add some texts to make it even clearer:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,3);

  \node[draw] (A) at (0,1) {A};
  \node[draw] (B) at (4,2) {B};

  \draw (A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So how to solve it? Of course, to join the *coordinates*, there is a standard solution with `\coordinate`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,3);

  \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
  \coordinate (B) at (4,2);

  \draw (A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or you can have the coordinates directly

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,3);

  \draw (0,1) -- (4,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to keep the nodes: you should use the coordinate (`<node name>`.*center*):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,3);

  \node (A) at (0,1) {};
  \node (B) at (4,2) {};

  \draw (A.center) -- (B.center);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or set option `coordinate` for the nodes (suggested by [Gregory Puleo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26762/gregory-puleo)):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,3);

  \node[coordinate] (A) at (0,1) {};
  \node[coordinate] (B) at (4,2) {};

  \draw (A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output of the above four codes:

[image]

Comment: Another option would be `\node[coordinate]` -- which is handy if you want a label at the point.

Comment: @GregoryPuleo Great! Thank you very much!