# node command while defining a coordinate in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is related to [Strange behavior in TikZ \draw command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480268/strange-behavior-in-tikz-draw-command) but is not the same.

While working with `coordinates` and `nodes` in TikZ, I was expecting that:

```
  \coordinate (x) at (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \coordinate (y) at (0,3) node[above] {$y$};
```

and

```
  \node[right] at (x) {$x$};
  \node[above] at (y) {$y$};
```

would yield the same result. But they don't. I get the following output:

[image]

With `\coordinate (x) at (4,0) node[right] {$x$};`, I meant, the system will create a node at `(4,0)` and will place the text `$x$` to its right.

Based on the output, I see the text `$x$` is placed at `(0,0)`, with the above command.

Why does this happen.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (x) at (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \coordinate (y) at (0,3) node[above] {$y$};

  \node[right] at (x) {$x$};
  \node[above] at (y) {$y$};

  \draw[<->,thick] (0,3) |- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why would they? Try `\path (x) node[right] {$x$};\path (y) node[above]  {$y$};`. If you give Ti*k*Z contradicting instructions, or place the instructions in the wrong order, you will get an unexpected result. BTW, you expect answerers to provide you with a full MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` etc. Could you please consider also using such an MWE in your question?

Comment: @marmot - I have added the MWE.

Comment: A trick to solve all these mysteries: just add `draw` option to the nodes, and you will probably see the difference.

Comment: @JouleV - That would still not explain why it happens. I am more interested in the why part.

Comment: The "why part" is simply that in `\coordinate (x) at (4,0) node[right] {$x$};` the `at (4,0)` gets eaten up by `\coordinate (x) at` and then Ti*k*Z "sees" `node[right] {$x$}` and inserts the default coordinate `(0,0)` to parse it.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't give you the expected result because the syntax is not appropriate. (At which level do you expect an explanation? Does it help that in `\coordinate (x) at (4,0) node[right] {$x$};` `at (4,0)` got "absorbed" by `coordinate (x)` so that Ti*k*Z adds the default coordinate `(0,0)` to interpret `node[right] {$x$}`?) You can condense all statements to one line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[<->,thick] (0,3) coordinate (y) node[above] {$y$} |- (4,0) coordinate (x)  node[right] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation. I want to notice that your "one line" can further be simplified to `\draw[<->,thick] (0,3) |- (4,0) node[right] {$x$} node[at start,above] {$y$};` since the coordinates (x) and (y) seems to be redundant for further purposes (IMHO). But I know you know that fact (you know everything about TikZ).

Comment: @MarianG. Thanks, I fully agree with that. I was not sure if the OP wants to do something with the coordinates later on, at least their names suggest something like `\begin{scope}[x={(x)},y={(y)}]`, so I kept them.

Answer (score 6):

In section 17.2.1 of the Ti*k*Z manual, the commands for such works are shown:

- `\path ... node ...` (1.1)
  or `\node ...` (1.2)
- `\path ... coordinate ...` (2.1)
  or `\coordinate ...` (2.2)

> **`\coordinate ... node ...` are *not* present** for the same job! In fact, since `\coordinate` is the same as `\path coordinate` so `\coordinate (x) at (4,0) node[right] {$x$};` is understood as
>
> ```
> \path coordinate (x) at (4,0);  % or `\coordinate (x) at (4,0);
> \path node[right] {$x$}; % (0,0) in case no coordinates are specified
> ```

This makes the outputs of `\coordinate (x) at (4,0) node[right] {$x$};` and `\node[right] at (x) {$x$};` not the same at all.

That is why we get

[image]

with this code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x) at (2,0) node[draw,right] {world};
\fill (x) circle (1pt)
    (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and we get

[image]

with this code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (x) at (2,0) {Hello} node[draw,right] {world};
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So how to solve it? We can't combine (2.2) or (1.2) with `... node ...`, but we can do it with (1.1) or (2.1):

```
\path (4,0) coordinate (x) node[right] {$x$};
```

Remember that `\draw`, `\fill`, `\filldraw`... are all daughters of `\path`, so they are all valid. But `\node` and `\coordinate` are **not** – they are less general versions of `\path`..

---

I found this using [the `draw` powerful trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481386/node-command-while-defining-a-coordinate-in-tikz#comment1216638_481386) :)

Comment: @Kpym Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 5):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections} not used in this mwe

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[label=right:$x$] (x) at (4,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:$y$] (y) at (0,3);

  \draw[<->,thick] (y) |- (x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
as response to [Martin Argerami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/28329/martin-argerami) coments below my answer, who is convinced that my answer not address op problem (and consequently he apparently down vote it, for what i'm very grateful. his message is very clear: don't show people some possible solution for which they not explicit ask). however let me note some my view on the problem:

- in answer i only suggest to see if my suggestion can help to op
- it solve the problem of placement of coordinate labels (in this is all about it, isn't it?)
- if the answer is not helpful, op can select one from other two answers as the best one and accept it.
- to be strict to Martins' consideration, that he should down vote many other answers, which try show another possibility to achieve op goal (nice picture, table, etc) or is written as exercise (personal or for op) ...
- on the end, i'm still convinced, that my answer not harm anyone, it only show another way how to draw coordinates shown in op mwe. is this worth for down voting it?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: is image not enough illustrative? the problem in question *is avoided* with use of `\coordinate` instead of nodes which also make code shorter.

Comment: The OP knows how to draw the image. The question was why his second set of commands didn't put the x and y where he expected them. That's an issue with tikz syntax, and it is addressed by the other answers.

Comment: well, why than complain on my answer? if op doesn't like mine solution, 
 (in which i show an alternative, to my opinion better solution for his/her problem) (s)he can accept one of other two answers.

Comment: I didn't complain; I stated that it doesn't address OP's question. If OP doesn't like your solution he can choose another answer. If I don't like you solution, I can downvote it. And I can certainly comment that your answer doesn't address OP's question.

Comment: so you decide to down vote it? thank you very much for this. however, some other people believe that answer has some value. at least it show how can someone solve this problem o different way.

Comment: Fair enough. But I don't understand your point: you think I don't have the right to downvote your answer if I think it's not good?